# Drupal 7 multisite domain without www. not working

Tags: 7, database, multi-sites

I have moved a site (www.example.com) to a multisite installation.  The path is 'sites/www.example.com'.  I am reading that adding the 'www' to the sites folder is a no-no.

www.example.com - Works but..

example.com - Doesn't.

I tried creating a symlink 'example.com -> /home1/username/public_html/sites/www.example.com/

also, tried adding "$sites['example.com'] = 'www.example.com';" to my sites.php, but..nothing.

If I rename the folder to 'example.com' all of the paths in the database will be broken.  Any ideas?

Comment: It's weird. it worked for me either way, both with `sites/www.example.com` and `sites/example.com`. What's in your htaccess? And does it work for you the other way around (except for the paths, of course, but does the site works)?

Comment: What are on the vhost? Which ip/url resolves when you try www.example.com or example.com?

Comment: Sorry guys!  It looks like the nameserver wasn't pointing correctly.  Thanks gerzenstl for your suggestion to look at what ip/url it resolves to!

Answer (score 0):

Rename the folder to example.com, create a 'sites.php' file in /sites, then add the following:

```
<?php
$sites = array (
  'www.example.com' => 'example.com',
);
```